# Expandable ListView onGroupExpanded & onGroupCollapsed

Tags: android, drawable, expandablelistview

guys i have 3 groups for my expandable listview,
i try to change the color of each group respectively, when they're expanding and back to normal color when they're collapsing...

the problem i've been facing right now is that when i click the first group, it changes the color of the last group..., so i can say that they colors changed randomly not to the corresponding group.

here's the simple code that i use:

```
listView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.group_bar_press);

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Group clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

well, that's all i hope it'll be solved :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i'm so sloppy :p

simply used Boolean isExpanded on my getView method, where i use to return my view,

and do it like this:

```
if(isExpanded){
   convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.press);
}else{
   convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal);
}
```

lol

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the getGroupView method in the ExpandableList Adapter with:

```
    if (isExpanded) {
       convertView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0db6a3);
    } else {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    }

    return convertView;
```

And all together the result is like this:

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    if (isExpanded) {
       convertView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0db6a3);
    } else {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, so did this: Instead of changing the color of one group, change the color of all 3 at the same time, whatever color you want.

May not be good solution but worked for me.